# MVC3 - model fields empty on post (using viewmodel)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, post, viewmodel

In an MVC3 application I have an entity with a strange behavior: the Create action works fine, but the Edit action fails: on submit I get the model with all the fields empty.

I searched for suggestions on this error, it seems that the ViewModel could be the cause, but I can't see any problem with mine. And as I said before, the creation works fine!

Please help, thank you!

Model:

```
    public partial class tblEmployeur
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredUserIDMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "UserIDDisplay")]
    public System.Guid userID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredNomMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "NomDisplay")]
    public string nom { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredTypeSocMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "TypeSocDisplay")]
    public string type_soc { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredCodeRCMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "CodeRCDisplay")]
    public string codeRC { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "AdresseDisplay")]
    public string adresse { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredVilleMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "VilleDisplay")]
    public string ville { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredWilayaMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "WilayaDisplay")]
    public int wilaya { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "Tel1Display")]
    public string tel1 { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "Tel2Display")]
    public string tel2 { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "FaxDisplay")]
    public string fax { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredEmailMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "EmailDisplay")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "SiteWebDisplay")]
    public string site_web { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredBanqueMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "BanqueDisplay")]
    public string banque { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredAgenceMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "AgenceDisplay")]
    public string agence { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredCompteMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "CompteDisplay")]
    public string nr_compte { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredDomaineMessage")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "DomaineDisplay")]
    public int domaine { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "NotesDisplay")]
    public string notes { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "LogoPetitDisplay")]
    public byte[] logo_petit { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(EmployeurResources), Name = "LogoGrandDisplay")]
    public byte[] logo_grand { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class EmployeurFormViewModel
{
    // Properties
    public tblEmployeur employeur { get; private set; }
    public SelectList Domaines { get; private set; }
    public SelectList Wilayas { get; private set; }
    public SelectList TypesSocietes { get; private set; }
    public string ActionToPerform { get; private set; }


    // Constructor
    public EmployeurFormViewModel(tblEmployeur unEmployeur, Guid employeurID, SelectList domList, SelectList Wils, SelectList typesSocsList)
    {
        employeur = unEmployeur;
         Domaines = domList;
         Wilayas = Wils;
         TypesSocietes = typesSocsList;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(unEmployeur.userID.ToString())||(string.Compare(unEmployeur.userID.ToString(), "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")==0))
        {
            unEmployeur.userID = employeurID;
            ActionToPerform = "Create";
        }
        else
        {
            ActionToPerform = "Edit";
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Employeur")]
    public ActionResult Create(Guid id)
    {
        tblEmployeur employeur = new tblEmployeur();
        SelectList domainesList = new SelectList(db.tblDomaines, "domaine_ID", "domaine");
        SelectList wilsList = new SelectList(db.tblWilayas, "wilaya_ID", "wilaya");
        SelectList typesSocList = new SelectList(typesSocRepository.GetAll());
        return View("Create", new EmployeurFormViewModel(employeur, id, domainesList, wilsList, typesSocList));
    }

    //
    // POST: /Employeur/Create

    [HttpPost, Authorize(Roles = "Employeur")]
    public ActionResult Create(tblEmployeur employeur, Guid id)
    {

        SelectList domainesList = new SelectList(db.tblDomaines, "domaine_ID", "domaine", employeur.domaine);
        SelectList wilsList = new SelectList(db.tblWilayas, "wilaya_ID", "wilaya");
        SelectList typesSocList = new SelectList(typesSocRepository.GetAll(), employeur.type_soc);

        IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult> validationResultsColl = db.GetValidationErrors();

        foreach (var validationResults in validationResultsColl)
        {
            foreach (var error in validationResults.ValidationErrors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, new Exception(error.ErrorMessage));
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                repository.Add(employeur);
                repository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Details");
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(validationError.PropertyName, new Exception(validationError.ErrorMessage));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddOtherError(ex);
            }
        }
        return View("Create", new EmployeurFormViewModel(employeur, id, domainesList, wilsList, typesSocList));

    }

    //
    // GET: /Employeur/Edit/5


    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    {
        tblEmployeur employeurCrt = db.tblEmployeurs.Find(id);
        SelectList domainesList = new SelectList(db.tblDomaines, "domaine_ID", "domaine", employeurCrt.domaine);
        SelectList wilsList = new SelectList(db.tblWilayas, "wilaya_ID", "wilaya", employeurCrt.wilaya);
        SelectList typesSocList = new SelectList(typesSocRepository.GetAll(), employeurCrt.type_soc);
        return View("Edit", new EmployeurFormViewModel(employeurCrt, id, domainesList, wilsList, typesSocList));
    }

    //
    // POST: /Employeur/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(tblEmployeur employeurCrt)
    {
        SelectList domainesList = new SelectList(db.tblDomaines, "domaine_ID", "domaine", employeurCrt.domaine);
        SelectList wilsList = new SelectList(db.tblWilayas, "wilaya_ID", "wilaya", employeurCrt.wilaya);
        SelectList typesSocList = new SelectList(typesSocRepository.GetAll(), employeurCrt.type_soc);

        IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult> validationResultsColl = db.GetValidationErrors();

        foreach (var validationResults in validationResultsColl)
        {
            foreach (var error in validationResults.ValidationErrors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, new Exception(error.ErrorMessage));
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                repository.Update(employeurCrt);
                repository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Details");
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(validationError.PropertyName, new Exception(validationError.ErrorMessage));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddOtherError(ex);
            }
        }
        return View("Edit", new EmployeurFormViewModel(employeurCrt, employeurCrt.userID, domainesList, wilsList, typesSocList));
     }
```

Edit view:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.EmployeurFormViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update employeur";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="text">
    <h1>
        Gestion du compte employeur</h1>
    <div style="height: 5px">
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Sauvegarde échouée. Veuillez corriger les erreurs et réessayer.")
        <p>@Html.ValidationMessage("_FORM")</p>

        <div class="validation-summary-errors">
            <span></span>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <fieldset style="width: 800px; line-height: 1.8em;">
            <legend>Update</legend>
            <table style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0; border: 1">
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.nom)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.nom, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.nom, "*")
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.employeur.userID, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        @Html.DropDownList("employeur.type_soc", Model.TypesSocietes)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.type_soc, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.codeRC)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.codeRC, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.codeRC, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.adresse)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.adresse, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.adresse, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.ville)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.ville, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.ville, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.wilaya)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.DropDownList("employeur.wilaya", Model.Wilayas, "Indiquez la wilaya", new { @style = "width: 232px;" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.wilaya)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.tel1)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.tel1, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.tel1, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.tel2)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.tel2, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.tel2, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.fax)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.fax, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.fax, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.email)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.email, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.email, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.site_web)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.site_web, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.site_web, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.banque)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.banque, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.banque, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.agence)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.agence, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.agence, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.nr_compte)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.employeur.nr_compte, new { @class = "input_txt_nofloat" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.nr_compte, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="padding: 0 0 0 0; height: 32px">
                    <td style="width: 180px; border: 0;">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeur.domaine)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        @Html.DropDownList("employeur.domaine", Model.Domaines, "Indiquez le domaine", new { @style = "width: 232px;" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeur.domaine, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 180px; height: 60px; border: 0;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        <input type="submit" value="Sauvegarder" class="submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    }
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Return", "Employeurs", "Home", null, new { @class = "link_no_underline" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come back with the answer at the question: ***why the Create action worked fine and the Edit did not:***

View model:

```
public tblEmployeur employeur { get; private set; }
```

Create HttpPost action:

```
public ActionResult Create(tblEmployeur **employeur**, Guid id)
```

Edit HttpPost action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(tblEmployeur **employeurCrt**)
```

The name of the Create action parameter was identical to the name of the property in the ViewModel, while in the Edit action the name was different.

In conclusion, both the following solutions are functional:

- either:

  ```
  public ActionResult Edit(tblEmployeur **employeur**)
  ```

  - or:

    ```
    public ActionResult Edit(EmployeurFormViewModel model) 
    { 
    tblEmployeur employeurCrt = model.employeur;
    ...
    ```

(and defining a parameterless constructor for the view model).

A thousand thanks to Dangerous, hope this will help somebody else too.

Answer (score 5):

In the view you specify that the model you are binding to is `EmployeurFormViewModel`:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.EmployeurFormViewModel
```

However, in you controller action you specify:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(tblEmployeur employeurCrt)
```

I therefore, believe that you will need to specify in the view:

```
@model [YOUR-NAMESPACE-HERE].tblEmployeur
```

and then everywhere that the model is referenced in the view (for example) it would be `model.wilaya` rather than `model.employeur.wilaya` etc.

You will also need to change the definition of:

```
public tblEmployeur employeur { get; private set; }
```

to:

```
public tblEmployeur employeur { get; set; }
```

so that it can be set by the default model binder and not just by the constructor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can not pass the model `@model [YOUR-NAMESPACE-HERE].tblEmployeur` to the view, because I need the Model.Wilayas drop down list as a source for the employeur.wilaya property. I changed `public tblEmployeur employeur { get; private set; }` to `public tblEmployeur employeur { get; set; }` but the model is still empty after submit.  What drives me mad is WHY the creation is OK, with the same model, model view and an identical view, and the edit does NOT!

Comment: I see what you mean about using `Model.Wilayas` in the drop down so you are right to continue to use `@model MyApp.ViewModels.EmployeurFormViewModel`.  Have you tried instead to declare your edit post action with the same model as that declared in the view?  I.e. `public ActionResult (EditEmployeurFormViewModel employeurFormModel)` and then to use this `employeurFormModel` in the action method which contains the `tblEmployeur` reference?  You would still need to not use the private set.

Comment: I changed the HttpPost methpd as you suggested, like this: `        public ActionResult Edit(EmployeurFormViewModel model)
       {
           tblEmployeur employeurCrt = model.employeur;`. Now I get this error: `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

Comment: You do not have a parameterless constructor defined for your view model which is required by the default model binder.  If you add a parameterless constructor in the view model (e.g. `public EmployeurFormViewModel() { //default code here if any }`) then you should be fine.  If you think that a parameterless constructor may not be appropriate to instantiate the view model then you should question the design of the view model since the view model should primarily be for passing information to/from the view.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I added the parameterless constructor for the view model and now it works fine. I thank you deeply for your support and your patience.